# Flow.js declare module with unnamed exports

Tags: flowtype

I'm declaring an export for an npm package that doesn't have any flow types. I've written one function so far but want to allow users to import any other functions that I have not declared without me having to declare them or know exactly what they are.

I've tried the following so far

```
//  flow-typed/myModule.js

declare module 'myModule' {
    declare module.exports: {
        concat(a: string, b: string): string;
        ...
    }
}

// index.js
import {
    concat, 
    someOtherFunction //error someOtherFunction doesn't exist. I do not want to declare this in module.exports but rather assume it exists since I haven't finished writing
} from 'myModule'
```

I've also tried adding | any and & any to the end of the module.exports line and nothing seems to have worked

Comment: Gave a shot but have no idea, tried adding `[key: string]: any` which is usually the approach but doesn't seem to do anything here. I'd just suggest you add `someOtherFunction: any` and all other funcs as you need it. I know it's more of a hassle but it does protect from importing an export and misspelling it.

Comment: ha yeah I tried the same. Think I may go with adding all the functions. Appreciate the effort.